# Display form input with Django

Tags: python, django, forms

So basically I want to make a simple form I can enter text and the after I hit submit, see the text.

Here is my forms.py:

```
class Search(forms.Form):
        search = forms.CharField()
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def search(request):
    context = RequestContext(request) 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = Search(data=request.POST)

        if search.is_valid():
             ticker = search.save()
             ticker.save()
             success = True

        else:
             print search.errors
    else:
        search = Search()       

    return render_to_response('ui/search.html', {"search":search},  context)
```

Here is the html form that you use to type in (I'm using bootstrap for styling purposes):

```
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="/search/" method="post" name="tick">
              {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter stock symbol">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

And finally, I want the text entered in the form to be displayed on "search.html" which looks like this currently:

```
{% extends 'ui/base.html' %}

{% block title %} search {% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
<br>
<p>test</p>
{{ form.search.data }} <!--I'm pretty sure this is not correct -->
{% endblock %}
```

Anyone know how I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: You can't call `save()` on a normal form; are you sure this is the exact code you are running? You also have other problems as not all execution paths return a HttpResponse object. Can you confirm if this is the exact code you are running?

Comment: I can comment out the the two lines with .save() and I get no errors. But I also dont get what I entered in the form, which is idealy what I would like to add to my template.

Answer (score 0):

Your template is wrong, as you suspect.

It is looking for a context variable named "`form`", but you have given it a context dictionary with a key named "`search`".

Also, "data" is the argument that you use to build up your `Search` object (correctly), but when you want to extract the user's input from it, you should use the field names instead, and you need to call `value()` on them in order to get the bound value. So, to get the contents of the text field called `search`, you should use `search.search.value`.

Try changing the line

```
{{ form.search.data }}
```

to

```
{{ search.search.value }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form name is `search`.

To render the value with modern django, you need to call the `value` method of the field, therefore your template should look like the following:

```
{{ search.search.value }}
```